# Laravel Repository eager load predefined accessor

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern, accessor

Just wanted to know if it is possible to eager-load a defined accessor in Laravel Repository. I am currently using this [l5-repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository) package and Laravel 5.4.

In my `UserInfo.php` model, I have this function

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return ucfirst($this->first_name . " ". $this->last_name);
}
```

Then I am trying to eager load that accessor in my controller like this.

```
$user_infos = $this->repository->with('full_name')->all(); 
// or $user_infos = $this->repository->with('getFullNameAttribute')->all();
return response()->json([ 'data' => $user_infos ]);
```

I know that it is not gonna work. I am just looking for a similar way to add my accessor `full_name` in my collection. So I don't need to concatenate in my front end. So my expected result would be

```
{
   id : 1,
   first_name : "Sample fname",
   last_name : "Sample lname",
   .....
   .....
   full_name : "Sample fname Sample lname",
}
```

Comment: The logic of eager loading is different with your situation. It will be used on relations and in this example it doesn't make any sense to use it.

Comment: Also, the accessor will be in available in your collection and you can use it. But if you want to create another collection, you can loop through this and insert it manually.

Comment: the problem is, i can only get the `full_name` when i loop that collection on my controller. I cannot access it in my front end (JS). Theres an update in my question i've added `return response()->json([ 'data' => $user_infos ]);`

Comment: Do you have alternatives? suggestion.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$appends` in your model `UserInfo.php`

```
protected $appends = ['full_name'];
```

This will append this custom field in your collection.

Then you can see it here :

```
$user_infos = UserInfo::all(); 
$user_infos->toJson();
```

You can see the appended accessor in the json.

Comment: Personally I don't like to use accessors. I want to extract it to a separate method and loop through collection to access it. But if you like you can do it.